# Iphone applications IDE

Tags: c#, iphone, windows, linux, ubuntu

I'm looking to start building Iphone apps. What IDE does uses Iphone developer, are there any nice ides for windows or linux platform with support of controls like android does,  or is there eclipse or netbeans plugin ?

Is it possible to develop iphone apps on visual studio platform ?

Please guide me first steps to start development on OS different than OSX.
Please link me to the tutorials or possible books on this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes , didn't find exact answer .

Comment: This has been discussed repeatedly.  Look at the "related" sidebar.

Comment: Type 'how do i start iphone development' and peruse the pages of almost exact same questions. Or even better, Google it.

Comment: I'm looking for tools that is not osx , not via virtual machine ... but thanks for your answers .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need either a Mac or a Virtual Machine running MacOs to be able to use XCode, the IDE for iPhone app development.

Comment: Valid to use OSX on Virtual Machine,however, why? what a drag - get a cheap mac mini - OSX should be enjoyed on the correct hardware and so should iPhone programming

Comment: Why buy a new computer just to run OSX?

Answer (score 2):

as far as my knowledge for developing iphone or mac apps you must use xcode tool(IDE).and moreover it should be instal in mac os only..

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that your question has the C# tag, You can use MonoTouch: http://ios.xamarin.com/.
You need to be running OSX anyways.